# How to divide svm_problem into 5 folds for custom cross validation - LIBSVM

Tags: java, data-structures, svm, libsvm, cross-validation

I am attempting to implement my own cross-validation function for LIBSVM, however I am confused on how to process the data structures that have been provided to me based on my input data.

The data is stored in a structure **svm_problem**:

```
public class svm_problem implements java.io.Serializable
{
    public int l;
    public double[] y;
    public svm_node[][] x;
}
```

Where: 
**l** is the length of the data set;
**y** is the array containing their target values;
**x** is an array of pointers, each of which point to a representation of one training vector.

**svm_node** is defined as:

```
public class svm_node implements java.io.Serializable
{
    public int index;
    public double value;
}
```

My goal is to split the training data into 5 folds, use 4 of them for training (function svm_train), and use the rest one to test the result (svm_predict) in order to find which value of C has the best prediction result (Based off error function).

My problem is how to separate the data into 5 folds given the structure of the data. How can the data structures be properly divided into 5 folds in order for me to proceed with the optimization of C.

I have been using this as a guide:
[A Practical Guide to Support Vector Classification](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/papers/guide/guide.pdf)

If someone could provide an example or a link to an example on how this is best done it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The `svm_problem` describes, for `i = 0, 1, ..., l - 1`, that `f(x[i])` should approximately equal `y[i]` for the learned function `f`.  Each tuple `(x[i], y[i])` can be thought of as a noisy sample from the function `f` that you are trying to find.

To split your dataset into training, cross validation, and testing datasets, you can simply split the set `{0, 1, ..., l - 1}` randomly into those 3 parts.  This is typically done by shuffling the list of numbers `0, 1, ..., l - 1` then saying "the first 60% of the numbers are training, the next 20% are cross validation, the next 20% are testing," or something similar to that. For each of those subset of the dataset, you can construct a new `svm_problem` that describes just that portion of the data.

Comment: I already have two data sets, one for training and one for testing. I am attempting to split the training data set into 5 folds in order to perform cross validation to find the best C value. This C value will be used when the entire data set is used to train an svm. I am unsure how to validate each set using the four others to find the best C. (C will be manually updated by me). Should the four other be combined and then passed into svm_train or should each one be passed into svm_train individually? The functions are included in Libsvm.

Comment: @MattKoczwara Assuming `svm_train` is incrementally updating the model parameters, it actually shouldn't matter whether you feed in four 20% `svm_problem` instances or one 80% `svm_problem` instance. I'm not familiar with the particular library, but the way I described splitting up the data is pretty universal when it comes to machine learning stuff.